# Bottom overflowed flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this problem where it appears that the bottom is overflowed but it isn't something concrete. My ui has this list view and it doesn't make sense to appear this. Any idea? The debugger said that the error is from column, what I should put instead?

[image]

```
Positioned(
                    left: 24,
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.3,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(widget.userName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 22,
                              )),
```

Comment: Please, provide a Minimal, Complete, Reproducible code sample if you want some targeted guidance.

Comment: Please provide the complete code of this page.